# How do I clear the '--rm' flag from an already-running Docker container?

Tags: linux, docker

I started a Docker container using `docker run --rm`, which tells it to delete the container when it stops. Right now it's still running, so it hasn't been deleted yet, but I changed my mind and no longer want to have it deleted when it stops. Is there a way to toggle the `--rm` flag on an existing container?

Answer (score 4):

You can preserve a container started with the `--rm` flag by committing the running container to a new image.

So, with your container that was started with `--rm` still running in one terminal, open another terminal and run:

```sh
$ docker image commit <running container name> <new image name>
```

Then you can create a new container from `<new image name>` *without* the `--rm` flag. That'll put you back to where you were when you ran `docker commit ...`.

Comment: docker commit <running container name> <new image name>

Answer (score 1):

No, that setting cannot be modified on a created container. You'll need to copy the container settings, logs, and filesystem changes you want to preserve out of the container, stop it (which deletes it), and recreate a new container with the desired changes.

Note that this is a key reason to treat containers as ephemeral. Configure the containers with a docker-compose.yml rather than a long `docker run` command line, store data in a volume, and make changes to the application and dependencies in the image using a Dockerfile. By following that workflow you avoid treating your containers as pets that need to be preserved and can easily delete and recreate them to a known good state with minimal downtime.

Comment: Alright. It wasn't anything irreplaceable anyway; I just thought it would be good to know. I'll accept your answer once I've given it a bit more time, on the off chance someone knows something you don't.